# How to access an already defined property of an anonymous linq object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-types

I've an answers dictionary object, ***ans*** and a LINQ query like this:

```
ans = new Dictionary<string,string>();
ans = LoadAnswers();

var milestones = LoadMilestones(session).Select(
                    m => new
                    {
                        milestoneid = GetSafeValue(m.Attribute("id").Value),
                        duedate = GetSafeValue(m.XPathValue("duedate")),
                        answer = ans[milestoneid]
                    }).ToArray()
```

Inside my milestones object, I've a property **answer** where I want to populate the data from **ans** object using **milestoneid** which is an already defined property. But this code won't compile, with error squiggly saying that *type x does not contain a definition for milestoneid*.

Since, GetSafeValue() is a huge method, I don't want to use it again to populate the answer property.

Q1) How can I use the ***milestoneid*** property for my answer ?

Q2) Also, I want to use ***ans.TrygetValue()*** to avoid null exceptions within that query. How to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are deserializing XML data. Why don't you use a library to do the deserialization?

Comment: @Aron we may in future, but this is just an example scenario. We may come across a situation like this in future, even when not dealing with XMLs.

Comment: Why don't you use `answer = ans[GetSafeValue(m.Attribute("id").Value)]` instead of `answer = ans[milestoneid]`?

Comment: @ekad GetSafeValue() is a huge method. And may get even bigger in future. All sorts of business logic validation is inside this method. That is our last resort for now, but I expect there to be a better method.

Comment: @MrClan in that case it sounds like its badly named. This entire solution has so many code smells. Anyway, try this `milestones.ToDictionary(x => x.milestoneid, x => x.answer);`

Comment: @Aron code smells ? Any suggestions to avoid them ?

Comment: Code smells are exactly that, they indicate deeper problems in your codebase. So the suggestion to how to avoid them is simply design better code. Without knowing exactly what you are doing I can't redesign your codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression after the `=>` can be a full fledged anonymous method that returns the new type. Hence you can hoist the values like so:

```
m => {
    var id = GetSafeValue(m.Attribute("id").Value);
    string answer;
    return new {
        milestoneid = id,
        duedate = GetSafeValue(m.XPathValue("duedate")),
        answer = ans.TryGetValue(id, out answer) ? answer : null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to use a variable that's being assigned to the anon object you are returning. Meaning, milestoneid is a property of the new object, not a local variable. You could do this: `ans[GetSafeValue(m.Attribute("id").Value)]`. That is adding some unfortunate duplication though, I would recommend something more like this:

```
var milestones = LoadMilestones(session).Select(
                m => {
                    var id = GetSafeValue(m.Attribute("id").Value);
                    return new
                    {
                        milestoneid = id,
                        duedate = GetSafeValue(m.XPathValue("duedate")),
                        answer = loadStudentResponse ? null : ans[id]]
                    };
                }).ToArray()
```

As for the second question, TryGetValue returns a bool, and has an out param.

```
object answer; // the type should be whatever you are expecting.
ans.TryGetValue(id, out answer);
```

Maybe something like:

```
var milestones = LoadMilestones(session).Select(
                m => {
                    var id = GetSafeValue(m.Attribute("id").Value);

                    object answer; // the type should be whatever you are expecting.
                    ans.TryGetValue(id, out answer);

                    return new
                    {
                        milestoneid = id,
                        duedate = GetSafeValue(m.XPathValue("duedate")),
                        answer = answer
                    };
                }).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could repeat the `GetSafeValue(m.Attribute("id").Value)` on the indexer when deriving answer (which isn't DRY), or instead, do a second projection to add fields derived from the initial projection:

```
var milestones = LoadMilestones(session)
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    milestoneid = GetSafeValue(m.Attribute("id").Value),
                    duedate = GetSafeValue(m.XPathValue("duedate")),
                })
                .Select(x => new 
                {
                   x.milestoneid,
                   x.duedate,
                   answer = ans[x.milestoneid]
                })
                .ToArray();
```

*(neouser99's single-pass extended lambda answer is better, IMO)*

Also, I'm not sure if this is actual code, but note that the below initialization is redundant

```
var ans = new Dictionary<string,string>();
ans = LoadAnswers();
```

Is reducable to just:

```
var ans = LoadAnswers();
```